# How to access variable in another file in node js

Tags: node.js, express

I have 2 files: export.js and server.js

I'm trying to access a variable in export.js in server.js, but I get undefined.

Note that I'm using knexjs and I gave it the name 'db';

**export.js**

```
let count;

const livePending = (db) => {
  db('cart')
  .count('id').where('status','=','Pending')
    .then(data => {
      if (data[0]) {
        count = data[0].count;
      }
    }).catch(err => res.status(400).send('DB Connection failed!'));
}

module.exports = {
    livePending: livePending,
    pCount: count
}
```

**server.js**

```
[...]
const anotherFile = require('./export');
anotherFile.livePending(db);
console.log(import.pCount);
```

When I try to console log inside the livePending function in export.js, I get the desired count which is 1.

The reason I'm doing this is to lessen the lines of code in my server.js.
If I do the exact same function in my server.js, I get the correct result.

Comment: The exported variable in `export.js` seems to be named `pCount`, not `count`. Try `console.log(import.pCount);` instead.

Comment: Beside the fact that the varaible name is pCount as @remix23 said, 
'import' is a reserved word in javascript so i think you should change the const name 'import'  to something else then import

Comment: sorry. fixed the code. that was my typo error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a small node app to test a variation of your code. Two important findings:

1.

```
const import = require('./export');
```

`import` is reserved (as well as `export`). Node will throw a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token` if you attempt to use either one as a variable name.

2.

```
console.log(import.count);
```

In your code, you're attempting to log a variable that's already been returned. You'll notice the log statement will return `undefined`. Instead, create a function that you can call to get the value from the actual variable in the other file.

To make things clearer, here's a little demo to show these concepts in action.

**export.js**

```js
let count;

const setCount = num => count = num;

const getCount = () => count;

// Shortcut: If the key: value is the same, we can just omit the value 
module.exports = {
  setCount,
  getCount
}
```

**server.js**

```js
const ex = require('./export');
ex.setCount(5);
console.log(ex.getCount()); // 5
```